# Unable to unpin VS Code workspace file in taskbar after removing this file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using workspace files in Visual Studio Code. A few months ago I pinned two workspace files in the taskbar:
[Pinned Workspaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt3Hi.png).
Lately, I removed one workspace file from my disc, but I cannot unpin this workspace from the taskbar. How can I do it without reinstalling VS Code?

I tried to do this with "Unpin from the list" but it doesn't work.
[Unpin workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4N4X.png)
I created a workspace file in the same location, but unpin still doesn't work.
Can I somehow unpin this workspace file without reinstalling VS Code?

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/145475